# Get highest two values when using group by in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

i have a table structure like this:

```
id | fname     |   lname    |   event    |     time    
---------------------------------------------------------
1    Name          One          1600m         4:37.00
2    Another       Name         1600m         4:55.00
3    Some          Person       1600m         4:27.00
4   Random         Name         1600m         5:04.00
```

there are many rows with many names, different events (track events) and times.

What I want to do do is get each person's lowest (fastest) two times for each event.

I already am able to use this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Times GROUP BY event, fname, lname ORDER BY time ASC
```

to get each person's lowest (fastest) time for each event.

How can I get each person's two lowest times using `GROUP BY`. (or any other way that is better.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server you could use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186734.aspx) and a common table expression. I haven't tested this but give it a go:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event, fname, lname ORDER BY time ASC) AS TopTimes 
   FROM Times 
   GROUP BY event, fname, lname 
   ORDER BY time ASC
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE TopTimes < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL dialects support the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  This is the best approach:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by event, fname, lname order by time asc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```